# SELECT does not execute into a OCI_FETCH_ARRAY loop

Tags: php, while-loop, oracle-call-interface

I found a situation where: when i have only one row for a result, after making a  SELECT query, i just do not enter into the while loop.

I just debug and can see it never enter the loop if there is only one result.

```
 if( count( oci_fetch_array( $result, OCI_ASSOC ) ) > 0 ) {

    while ( ( $row = oci_fetch_array( $result, OCI_ASSOC ) ) != false ){
      //code processing
   }

 }
```

How can i enter the while loop, even if i have only one row as a resultset ?

when i have many rows i do enter the loop normally.

Comment: There's no reason for the `if()` conditional here, the `while` is taking care of whether or not the result is available to you. Lose it.

Comment: Yes it work´s ! Thank you!